# The free Delphi 2006 compiler

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

On Wikipedia I read:

> **Borland Delphi 2006** [...] Each version is available in two editions:
>   Explorer—a free downloadable
>   version—and Professional

Is this edition still available? Or are people who grabbed it in 2006 lucky and the others not that much?

Comment: Proper name is the "Turbo Delphi Exploper". You obtain a copy of product itself (quite possible, i even have magazine with turbo D amongst the other promo discs) but they are no longer issuing license keys to the new users (try local flea market). BTW, there was another free version "Delphi 7 Personal" (status is exactly the same - abandoned)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no free Delphi versions now. You can use free Turbo Delphi only if you already have the product keyfile, but you can't obtain new free Turbo Delphi keyfile anymore.

Comment: There is still a low cost (150$) Delphi XE Starter Edition. It is the latest version of Delphi. You can also use the trial edition for a month.

Comment: @jszpilewski: one should very carefully look at the differences to the Pro version, though. Some of the limitations in the Starter would have been unacceptable for me.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Agree, but the starter edition may still be more than enough for someone interested in Turbo 2006

Answer (score 3):

Lazarus Free Pascal is free and OpenSource, it is very similar to Delphi.

Comment: On one hand I agree. Especially very similar to the older versions of Delphi around Delphi 5 (and I mean that all around positive). However, it comes with other quirks and limitations. Still +1 for pointing it out.

Comment: Currently I have a dll (for JNI) using DirectShow thru DSPack. I'm afraid it would take a huge effort to port that to FreePascal.